# Get an increasing number with JavaScript every day?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get an incresing number in JavaScript? The number should increase from 1 to 6 every day. Example:

1st day: 3
2nd day: 5 (3+2)
3rd day: 6 (5+1)
4th day: 12 (6+6)
5th day: 16 (12+4)
...

I guess I need some base value because I can not save the numbers anywhere. I tried using the following code as base value:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

But this value is just too big.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: I think you should be a bit clearer on what you are trying to achieve. Is there a reference date? There also seems to be no pattern to the increment.

Comment: There is a pattern, it should be randomly increased by either 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6.

Comment: Oh just divide `new Date().getTime()` by `86400000`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, given your comments I think this should be what you are looking for:

```
var rand_num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1); 
var result = index_num + rand_num
```

This `result` will be whatever index you deliver plus a random integer between one and six inclusive. Just use result as the next index for each subsequent day.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1o80n8z/1/)

```
var day1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
var day2 = day1 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
```